# Is there a class like Optional but for non-optionals?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

It is handy to declare Functions to map values and consume them if they are present.

In the situation that you have several mandatory objects, and several Optionals, I find myself wrapping the others in Optional.of(mandatoryObject) as well so I can use the same expressions on them without writing it all backwards.

```
Food vegetables = Food.someVegetables();
Optional<Food> condiment = Food.someCondiment();
Optional<Food> spices = Food.someSpices();

condiment.map(prepare).ifPresent(putOnPlate);
spices.map(prepare).ifPresent(putOnPlate);
```

But then I don't like this code:

```
putOnPlate.accept(prepare.apply(vegetables));
```

so I wrap it:

```
Optional.of(vegetables).map(prepare).ifPresent(putOnPlate);
```

But that is just wrong, because the vegetables (in this example) are not in fact optional. They are very important and I just gave everyone the impression that they are optional.

So my question is : Is there some class in java like java.util.Mandatory so I can write:

```
Mandatory.of(vegetables).map(prepare).definitelyPresentSo(putOnPlate);
```

Comment: This is an excellent question. I can't wait to see the answers.

Comment: I know I should not comment this, but I laughed so hard at .definitelyPresentSo

Comment: Your assertion of "definitely present" certainly depends on the /run-time semantics/ of `prepare`, as well as the "mandatory" status of the target.   So there's no way to use such a thing safely - the system could not assure `prepare` behaves in any particular way..   I suppose it could throw an exception if a value is not present?  But that's a) rather different from what you are asking, and b) totally breaks a lot of the use cases this fluent pattern is intended for.

Comment: It doesn't help you with Java 8 optionals, but just adding as an historical note that Guava `Optional` has a subclass called [`Present`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Present.java), which is the subclass of optional when the value is, well, present, which sounds a bit like what you're asking for here.

Comment: `Optional.of` already enforces presence, you would have to use `Optional.ofNullable` to allow the creation of empty optionals.

Comment: you want to read this: https://medium.com/@anicolaspp/operator-in-scala-cbca7b939fc0#.l2ycba6as

Comment: @BadZen Something like that might perhaps work if this `Mandatory` only provides a  `flatMap` method that accepts a function that is required to return a `Mandatory` itself, but that would probably reduce its usefullness even further.

Comment: Yeah, that's not much of a `map` pattern.  =/

Comment: If optional is split into some/none types, then you could declare the mandatory ones as some rather than none.

Comment: Your `Mandatory` sounds like the `Identity` monad

Comment: Wow, I did not expect so much useful feedback! Learning a lot, and Sorry for not returning to check until now. I'm going to go through all the responses. This is gold, thanks all!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there is such an API. You may replace

```
Optional.of(vegetables).map(prepare).ifPresent(putOnPlate);
```

with

```
Stream.of(vegetables).map(prepare).forEach(putOnPlate);
```

now having to live with the fact that the single-element `Stream` is a special case of the stream of arbitrary elements (including the possible empty stream).

But you can handle all mandatory elements at once

```
Stream.of(mandatory1, mandatory2, mandatory3 /* etc */).map(prepare).forEach(putOnPlate);
```

It would be even possible to incorporate the optional elements, but it will not be as convenient as it should be, as [`Optional.stream()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) will be introduced not until Java 9.

Comment: Actually, Optional is a Stream that can hold max 1 element :)

Comment: @pivovarit: you can see it this way, but `Optional` supports only a subset of the `Stream` operations. On the other hand, it has the `get()` method to retrieve its sole element, whereas the `Stream` counterpart is `findAny()` which will return an `Optional`…

Comment: this is not my invention. In FP, it's common to treat containers such as Optional, Try like iterables. Check this code https://github.com/javaslang/javaslang/blob/3a6f36dc6de3435c8fc26202aff4b799c2f2a384/javaslang/src/main/java/javaslang/Value.java

Comment: @pivovarit: sure, `Optional` and `Stream` are both specializations of the same concept (even if they don’t implement `Iterable`), but it could cause long debates whether Optional is a special Stream or Stream an extended Optional, but technically, `Optional` and `Stream` are distinct classes not having a common interface nor a superclass other than `java.lang.Object`—unfortunately.

Comment: sure, just one note. I did not write this to harm your answer. Just sparking some ideas :)

Comment: For analogy, consider `Arrays.asList(oneItem)` versus `Collections.singletonList(oneItem)`. The former is a special case of an arbitrary-length list that happens to contain one item. The latter is an optimized implementation of a list that can only contain one item, without any overhead. If `Stream.of(oneItem)` is analogous to `Arrays.asList(oneItem)`, then why don't we have a Stream analogy for `Collections.singletonList`? (I guess the answer might be that there's no real need for one?)

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou: if you look closer at [`Stream.of(item)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) and [`Stream.of(firstItem, …)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-), you’ll notice that there *is* a specialization for the single-element case. It’s just the same syntax as there is no conceptual difference. `Arrays.asList` is a different beast, it’s original purpose doesn’t fit its newer varargs nature. Java 9 will solve this; there you can write `List.of(singleItem)` or `List.of(first, second)` or `List.of(…)`.

Comment: Awsome. The identical syntax had fooled me.

Answer (score 10):

The main idea behind `Optional` is abstracting nullability(getting rid of null checks) and providing a fluent API for working with optional values.

In the case of a value that is always present, there is nothing to abstract(at least nothing with a practical value) so no such tools exist in the pure Java.

In other functional languages, you have multiple 'monadic' tools like `Optional` available for different use-cases. If you want to bring them to Java, [Javaslang](http://javaslang.io) is probably the best place to look at. You can find there tools like `Option`, `Try`, `Lazy`, `Validation`, `Either`, `Future`, `Tuple` and the whole `Collections API` that allows coding in a similar fashion you described.

Answer (score 4):

I might be wrong, but if you don't like to use `Optional` you can just use a `Stream` of just one object. So instead of

```
Optional.of(vegetables).map(prepare).ifPresent(putOnPlate);
```

you can just use:

```
Stream.of(vegetables).map(prepare).forEach(putOnPlate);
```

The result is going to be identical. Both methods will throw `NPE` if vegetables are null.

```
Arrays.asList(10, null).forEach(value -> {
        Optional.of(value).map(x -> x.toString()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
        Stream.of(value).map(x -> x.toString()).forEach(System.out::println);
});
```

NPE safe version is going to be

```
 Optional.ofNullable(value).map(x -> x.toString()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
 Stream.of(value).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(x -> x.toString()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

`Optional` is just a container for an object which may or may not contain a non-null value.

Comment: Note that the `null` treatment of `Optional.of(value)` and `Stream.of(value)` differs, as `Optional.of(value)` will throw immediately when `value` is `null` whereas, `Stream.of(value)` does not and will only throw in your example due to the subsequently chained operation (`x.toString()`).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the type `@NonNull Food`.

Comment: The OP is looking for something that provides a fluent-style API with smooth interaction with Lambdas/Function references while clearly communicating and ideally enforcing non-nullability.